# SVG with mask injected in iFrame is broken in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, svg, mask

I'm trying to inject a SVG with a mask reference into an iframe.
It is a constraint. I have to work with iframes and inject SVG in them.

It looks like the mask url `url(#mask1)` cannot be resolved in Firefox unless I'm using an `src` attribute linking to an external SVG, or not using iframes at all (which I cannot do).

The behaviour in Chrome is what I'm looking for (see attached screenshots).

How can I reference the mask in that context to make this work in Firefox?

See Plunker below for easy testing:

http://plnkr.co/edit/CR82bQhifvSg4QhnS7fg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>svg in iframe populated with JS (mask url broken in FF)</h1>
    <iframe class="container"></iframe>
    <h1>svg in iframe populated with src</h1>
    <iframe class="container" src="svg.html"></iframe>
    <h1>svg in div populated with JS</h1>
    <div id="raw-svg" class="container"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">' +

 // Blue square
 '<rect style="stroke: none;fill: #0000ff; mask: url(#mask1)" width="100" height="100"></rect>' +

 // Mask (upper half of the blue square)
 '<defs><mask id="mask1" width="100" height="100">' + 
 '<rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" style="stroke:none;fill: #ffffff"></rect>' +
 '</mask></defs>' + 

 '</svg>';

var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = svg;
document.getElementById('raw-svg').innerHTML = svg;
```

Chrome rendering

[image: chrome]

Firefox rendering

[image: firefox]

Comment: raise a bug in bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core

Answer (score 1):

I've been fighting this for some time, and suddenly realized that it works if you prepend the local URI with `about:blank` (e.g., `url(about:blank#mask1)`).

I reported this here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1157953